# Change Outlook palette win32com?

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

As the title of this message suggests I'm willing to change `Outlook` palette from its default (in my case it is `Office`) to `Slipstream`using Python's `win32com` (as the rest og my snippet code is based on it).

I went through [Outlook object model documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook) but couldn't quite find what I was looking for. So I couldn't go to the win32com side to find its match.

Below I'm showing the actual Outlook menu if I were to change the color palette manually.

[image]

It would be nice if someone could provide me with pointers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that. The colors are used for editing emails, so it makes sense to check out the Word object model for color-related properties such as [Font.ColorIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.font.colorindex) property which returns or sets a [WdColorIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdcolorindex) constant that represents the color for the specified font. Outlook uses Word for rendering message bodies.

You may also find the [How the color palette works](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm) page helpful.

Comment: thank you for your reply. i saw it just now.